# Can't update mac book (can't reinstall system)

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

I can't update my MacBook Pro 13" mid 2019 (running macOS Catalina) (10.15.4 )to 10.15.5 or even 10.15.6.

When I try to do it, the MacBook Pro restarts again and again.

I can't access to Apple Diagnostics from <kbd>D</kbd> key at bootstrap (MacBook Pro reboot)

I have tried to reset SMC and PRAM.

I have tried to reinstall macOS from hidden partition or from bootable USB. The MacBook Pro just restarts

I have done a RAM test with [Rember](https://www.kelleycomputing.net/rember/), a disk test with [DriveDx](https://binaryfruit.com/drivedx) and a CPU test with [prime95](https://www.mersenne.org/download/) and everything seems okay.

When I log into my session I get this error:

```
Core: 0 
  IA32_MC0_STATUS=0xB200000000000406
  IA32_MC0_CTL=0x0
Core: 0
  IA32_MC3_STATUS=0xBE00000000800400
  IA32_MC3_CTL=0x0
  IA32_MC3_ADDR=0xFFFFFF800F2FA675
  IA32_MC3_MISC=0xFFFFFF800F2FA675
```

I don't know what to try more.

Comment: It sounds like you've done everything you can do short of taking it to an Apple authorized service technician. It sounds like a hardware problem. Using the hardware diagnostics would normally be the next move, but since even that isn't working for you, it's time to bring it to someone who can open it up and diagnose the hardware fault.

Comment: You **did** go into Recovery Mode and run Disk Utility on the boot drive? Did you also try and reinstall macOS *from Recovery Mode* or did you use another method like booting from a USB installer? Also does the Mac boot normally and work normally? EG Can you log in and run apps?

Comment: Yes I can log in and work with my mac. But I can't go into Recovery Mode, the mac reboot before.